# Incremento de variável com onMouseOver (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, funções, auto-incremento

estou iniciando em JS e estou com dúvidas de onde estou errando na função abaixo?
Preciso que a var score obtenha incremento de +1 sempre que passar o mouse sobre o conteúdo de uma imagem, mas na forma que desenvolvi ela fica sempre em "0".

```js
var score = 0;

function rastro(){
  document.getElementById("visto").score = score + 1;
  alert("Mensagem: " + score);
}
```

```html
 <div id="visto" onMouseOver="rastro()">
    <div class="fundo1">
        <div class="center">
            <img src="img/cont_1.png" class="img-fluid" width="70%">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você não está incrementando a variável `score`.   Observe que você está incrementando um **atributo** `score`, membro do elemento HTML com ID `visto`.

Tente algo assim:

```js
var score = 0;

function rastro(){
  score = score + 1
  document.getElementById("visualizacoes").innerText = score;
}
```

```css
.center{
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="visto" onMouseOver="rastro()">
    <div class="fundo1">
        <div class="center">
            <!-- imagem removida --> 
            <!--img src="img/cont_1.png" class="img-fluid" width="70%" -->
            <span id="visualizacoes"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Obrigado Marcos!

Comment: Disponha... Estamos aqui para isso. Lembre-se de aceitar as respostas para não deixar pendências. Abraço.